# In Django Rest Framework, how can the backend check if the files upload is multiple or not?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Client UI can either send a single file or a multiple files.
When my backend receives it, I want to check whether it is a single or multiple files.
If it is single, I just pass it straight (This is working already).
But if it is a multiple files, I want to zip it first, and then pass it.

I am stuck figuring out where Django Rest Framework do their validation.
I tried both in Serializer and also in Views

```
class CTDWorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


  class Meta:
    model = CTDWork
    fields = ('wo_id', 'owner', 'created',
            'purpose', 'work_type',
            'reviewer', 'status', 'upload', 'download')
    read_only_fields = ('download',)

  def update(self, validated_data):
    print "foo"
    return validated_data
```

and:

```
class CTDWorkDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  queryset = CTDWork.objects.all()
  serializer_class = CTDWorkSerializer
  permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsCurrentUserOrAdmin)
  parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)

  def perform_update(self,serializer,format=None):
    print "bar"
```

I am thinking to use the request.FILES.getlist("files") in the views, but the server always reject the request before it can print something on my log.
Any idea, why is it happened? Where and when does Django validate and reject the http request? Thanks

Comment: Try overriding your view’s `post()` (or whatever HTTP verb you use) method, and see if your serializer has `self.context['request']` available

Comment: Tony, how to override my view's put() ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah thanks to Tony, I can print out with the overriding put

```
class CTDWorkDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  queryset = CTDWork.objects.all()
  serializer_class = CTDWorkSerializer
  permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsCurrentUserOrAdmin)
  parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)

  def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print request.data.get('upload')

    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Currently, when I tried to print the request.data, it shows the uploaded files as "unicode": u'upload': [u'[object FileList]'],